# jQuery - how to remove .submit() and .focus() events

Tags: javascript, jquery

The function that holds these events is called every time a popup window is opened

I have a function that I need to call several times on a page. The function contains some `.on("click", function....` events.

In order that I don't keep adding more and more click events to the same element I'm preceding every `.on("click",` with `.off("click",` which (I understand) to be the correct way to handle this?

My function also has the following:
`$("#myForm").submit(function(e){...`
And...
`$("#myTextArea").focus(function(e){...`

My questions are:
Do I need to "unbind" (for want of a better word) the .submit and .focus functions the same way as I do the "click" function in order to stop these events multiplying on those elements every time the function is called?

And, if I do, what is the correct way to do this?

Many thanks

John :-)

** Update ** 
I have included a bit more detail as requested.

My page includes 3 popup windows initiated by 3 separate buttons. The popup windows start life with just a "loading.gif" in them. As each button is clicked I test to see if the "loading.gif" is active in the window and, if it is, I use an ajax request to fetch the correct HTML for that window.

Once my ajax request comes back with the HTML I append it to the window and then call this function to bind events to the relevant buttons/forms etc.

If they then close that window and open one of the other popups I need to re-call the function and so want to make sure that I'm not doubling up on events for each HTML element. Therefore I turn the events `.off` first before putting them back `.on`.

Hope that clarifies the reasoning behind the question but feel free to ask if it's not clear. I also think it prudent to point out that I'm a newbie to jQuery (in fact javascript in general really) so this is certainly not necessarily the best/only way to achieve this functionality. It's just the way that made sense to me at the time of writing the code.

Originally I had the popup windows pre-populated with the HTML but hidden but I found that my page size was quite large that way and I wanted to improve load times etc.

---

Comment: Provide more context regarding your posted code: `every time the function is called` which function? How do you call it?  Sounds like a XY problem, you'd surely have better to delegate events

Comment: @A.Wolff I've updated the question with a bit more information. Thank you :-)

Comment: So you should use delegation as in already posted answer, see: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the way you are doing. You can also use the jQuery delegation system.

Example :

You have a div (let's call it `#test`) and you add some buttons in it. You remove the buttons, you add them again ... But you want to bind a click event on them. You can do this :

```
$('#test').on('click', 'button', function(event) {
    // Do what you want. this == the clicked button
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Explanations :

The click event is binded on `#test`, but jQuery will test the clicked target against the css selector `button`. And the `this` will be the clicked target (not `#test`). This way you create your click listener only once and you don't have to add/remove it every time you create a button.

Answer (score 3):

You try use `preventDefault`.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   //to do anything
});
```